# DJANGO How to filter queryset with ListView?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset, django-urls

I'm currently building a website with Django and my problem is the following : I have a page, home, which goal is to display all Plat objects in the database (Plat is a model from the database). What I want is having kind of a filtering table next to the list, which enables to filter the objects on various attributes. For example, we could filter the objects with a price greater than 10 euros, or the objects with a certain attribute lower than 5, or both at the same time.

here are the relevant parts of my files :

views.py

```
class home(ListView):
    model = Plat
    context_object_name = "plats"
    template_name = "actualites/home.html"
    paginate_by = 9
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home', views.home.as_view(), name = 'home'),
]
```

The home.html file is made with bootstrap and is really big so I will not display it since I don't think it's much useful. A solution to my problem may be to put parameters in the url `path('home/<int:price>', views.home.as_view(), name = 'home'),` and overwrite get_queryset in the home view `def get_queryset(self):
        return Plat.objects.filter(prix=self.kwargs['price'])`
The problem is that the filtering can be done on many attributes so my url would be really big, like `home/<int:attr1_min_value>/<int:attr1_max_value>/<int:attr2_min_value>/......` Moreover, I would have to put default value for parameters for example attr2_min_value = 0 by default to enable me to filter only on attr1. But I don't think it's possible with Django. And I'm not sure about how to make the link between the filter buttons in the template and the arguments in the url.

What is the correct way to proceed?

Comment: The django-filters packages provides a lot of the functionality you are after https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-filter

Comment: I did what you are looking for, but I did not care about passing filters through url. Is it a must for you?

Comment: Iain thanks I will check that ! KrazyMax no it's absolutely not a must for me, I don't like passing arguments through the url so if you have a solution I'm listening

Comment: Indeed the django filters enable me to do what I wanted. If someone is also interested I would recommand this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html